# Верстка xml файлов для Аndroid?

Tags: xml, android, вёрстка

Всем привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где есть учебники верстки Xml файлов для Аndroid?

Как правильно ее делать, какие подводные камни есть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо не учебник искать, а документацию смотреть.

Для начала ознакомиться со списком доступных компонентов. Почитать про каждый из них. А уже потом, по мере надобности, углублять знания по конкретным из них.

Подводных камней слёту могу два назвать:

1) Совместимость в различных версиях Android. Почитать про Support Library, про компоненты вроде ActionBarSherlock и т.д.

2) Не делать слишком большую вложенность слоёв друг в друга, иначе будут краши. Забавность в том, что количество не регламентировано. Где-то на вложенности 15 будет крашиться, где-то на 20. В группе Google рекомендуют никогда больше 15 не делать.

Comment: вложенность 15 вы имеете в виду что бы вложенность не была 15 уровня?
т.е. так можно ?
Linear lyott
   button
Linear lyott
   button
Linear lyott
   button

Comment: 15 уровня, да.